# Primary cell chemistry with the highest volumetric power density

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

I am working on a project (a disposible device) which requires significant power delivery from a small volume. This power delivery is very bursty, we're talking a handful of big pulses over the service life of the device. This is all super up in the air right now, but I am looking at around 0.35 mL of volume for the battery and I need to pump around 150 mW into a resistive load for a burst on the order of ten seconds (in order to heat something up). Primary cells are preferred for shelf life but secondary cells which can hold substantial charge for 2-3 years would be acceptable.

In order to bound the problem, I'd like to figure out what primary cell chemistry has the best volumetric power (not energy) density. Mass is not a concern. This would at least let me know what's physically possible, even if it's not neccessarily available off-the-shelf as a finished cell that fits exactly in my volume available.

I have started by taking a look at the [comparison of commercial battery types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_commercial_battery_types) article on Wikipedia. By dividing the volumetric energy density by the mass energy density of the battery, I can get the battery's density. From there, I can calculate the volumetric power density by multiplying by the specific power.

Unfortunately, Wikipedia's table isn't very complete, and is missing the specific power for a bunch of primary cell chemistries.

So, my question is: does anyone know what commercially-available primary cell chemistry has the highest volumetric power density? I am not adverse to paying NRE for a custom cell shape, but I need a battery chemistry which is used commercially, not something that's currently just a university research project.

PS: It also probably goes without saying, but [molten-salt batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molten-salt_battery), while technically a commercially available primary cell, are not practical for my application.

Comment: Most phone manufacturers seem to be using lithium technology (li-po...) for exactly the reasons you state : limited volume etc

Comment: Normally % Load regulation is defined ratio of ESR source/load.  What are your load specs? (R,X) and volume specs?

Comment: Why primary cell? Is rechargable out? Is it shelf life (10y primary, 1y rechargable)? A supercap or 100C LiPo can give huge output power, and be recharged from a high energy low power primary cell. You need to be more specific about your requirements for lifetime, total energy, peak power, energy of the burst.  (edit) I like Jonk's idea, that's serious power, so, you need to reveal a lot more information, editted into the OP please, not spread out over comments (/edit)

Comment: What is this energy to be converted into? I don't see any description, at all. I might therefore recommend a magazine of small, relatively safe explosive charges -- as in a rifle cartridge, for example. Given my ignorance, anyway. You only need a few, you say. So? A good answer only comes with some exchange of information. You need to start that process by allowing us to understand what the energy will be used to achieve. Better answers will be found that way. Otherwise, you are just forcing us through a contrived mental process. Which is more of a game, than reality.

Comment: What are your complex load specs? and volume specs? While batteries can be defined by C+ESR over some SoC range

Comment: @Neil_UK Yep, mainly shelf life concerns (ideally want 2-3 years). Will update energy/volume specs momentarily.

Comment: Peter, Zinc Air has the highest Volumetric Energy density but also much higher cost /Volume. No Limit?  But in the 70's for aerospace we only used silver oxide batteries **which I can't imagine you could afford now,** if energy size is large like a cordless drill. $$$$

Comment: So to give us some perspective, and save us working it out (because I'm sure you already have), how far is a CR2032 away from your target volume and power output? Factor of 2? Order of amgnitude?

Comment: @jonk I apologize for the XY problem, but this one really is a basic cell chemistry question on power density. Suffice it to say I have a large list of potential solutions to the underlying problem I'm trying to solve, but they all require varying amounts of power into resistive loads. What I'm trying to do is feel out the solution space by determining what what my volume/power tradeoff is so I can downselect before we go too hog wild designing something we can't possibly hope to power. I'd really love to go into detail on the underlying application but it's for work.

Comment: @Neil_UK Current space budget is a 5mm tall by 10mm diameter volume. I can't really play with that envelope all that much, a CR2032 is much too physically large.

Comment: Peter you dont need to define your project ( secret aerospace work) but you do need to define the step load R+jX and allowed Vmin or max voltage drop

Comment: @PeterK That's fine. It just ceases to be interesting to me, then. I just happen to enjoy being allowed to explore creative ways of solving problems. This doesn't allow that. I'm sure there is plenty of good answers for you, though. Best wishes!

Comment: Zinc air batteries can't be kept in service for two to three years, can they?

Comment: @mkeith Nope. Once opened to air, that's it. Short lifetime.

Comment: Of course a CR2032 is too large, but there are smaller cells in that family. How far is the pulse power of the technolocgy short of your 150mW for 10 seconds per 350uL ratio? Factor of 2? One or two orders of magntidude?

Comment: Duracell report I am readings says "At 21 ºC (70 ºF) storage, a
sealed zinc air cell retains 98% of rated
capacity over a one-year period. Zinc-air cells
are best if used within 3 years of
manufacture."

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, while sealed, they can't power a load. But they last great. But once unsealed, I think they only last a few weeks or so.

Comment: doh , right,, which gets me back to load specs ??  "Silver oxide  provides up to 40 percent more run time than lithium-ion batteries and also feature a water-based chemistry that is free from the thermal runaway and flammability problems that have plagued the lithium-ion alternatives."

Comment: @Neil_UK: A CR2032 (Lithium Manganese Dioxide chemistry) will suffer that just fine, but as the battery gets smaller the internal resistance increases dramatically. I tested out a CR927 and the internal resistance was on the order of 150 ohms @ DC, so by the maximum power transfer theorum I can only pull about 15mW per cell.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 It's just a pure resistive load for generating a small amount of heat (as mentioned in the post, around 100 mW). I've got full latitude to screw with the size of that resistance to maximize power transfer, or even do something fancy like use a switching converter to match impedances. The issue is getting enough power in the first place.

Comment: I have come across (in various travels) some very small li-ion batteries (custom made) that might be the best you can get for high surges and your 0.3ml size limit.  Zinc-air batteries have high energy density but miserable power density. We were actually looking at one that was ITAR (and if you need to ask the cost...)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am okay with custom :). Cost is not a problem as long as there's potential to scale, but ITAR would be. Do you happen to know what chemistry those cells were?

Comment: Not sure the exact chemistry (one can only ask so many questions sometimes) but definitely a Li-based rechargeable cell.  And no export problems, except perhaps to the usual bad actors.

Comment: Since you just want heat, can you colocate the cell with the heat to use the internal resistance as well, or do things need to get too hot?

Comment: Does it really take 20 comments to get 1 good spec?

Comment: At least for comparison purposes also look at a stack of small button cells such as alkaline or silver oxide. Mercury was good but that ship has sailed.

Comment: you know, putting 'I tried a CR927, but it was an order of magnitude too low on power output' in the OP a) shows research and b) gives us a leg-up on solutions, good for both you and us.

Answer (score 1):

### Assumed essential Specs:

Volume: "5mm tall by 10mm diameter"
Power:  150mW power transfer momentary but over a 3 yr span
Type:  Primary cell
Energy:  TBD
Pulse duration: TBD
Temperature: TBD
Budget: TBD  Not critical
Misc. Stress Factors: Ground Benign

### Suggested solution:

**2x SR57 Silver Oxide Buttons**
Size: 9.5 mmD x 2.55 mmT  ( 5.1mm thick for two) +/-<5%

[image]

**Designation: ANSI-1162SO/1165SO, IEC-SR57**
Nominal Voltage: 1.55 Volts
Typical Capacity: 51 mAh* (to 1.2 volts)
Capacity Test: 22K ohm continuous drain at 21°C
Typical Weight: 0.8 grams (0.03 oz.)
Typical Volume: 0.19 cubic centimeters (0.012 cubic inch)
Impedance (40 Hz): 10 to 25 ohms

### Assumptions:

two cells ideally 440 watt-seconds (51 mAh * 3600s * 1.2V * 2bat )
    must be derated by load life profile = TBD
    perhaps derated to 1% of ideal with 22 kohm load

> Average Capacitance in Farads, using E= C (Vi²-Vf²) depends on useful V range
>
> Pd Max load = ½ Pd short cct. or matched impedance to battery string ESR.

est. Short Circuit Power = P=V²/Z = 1.2²/(10 to 25) per cell  x2
est. Pmax = 1/2 of Psc = 1/2 x 280 mW max

> **Pmax = 140 mW @ 1.2V with   Voc = 2.4 V and 20 ohm load**
>
> **( This is insufficient but closest match 150 mW )**

Datasheet:http://www.microbattery.com/microbat/pdf/energizer/energizer-watch-battery-042-2014.pdf

Comment: 10mm * 5mm is not volume... But still a good answer.

Comment: @SolarMike  Thanks for the suggestion/err compliment Mike ...

Comment: Which reminds me to tell everyone, a better answer only comes from better specs...